# FilterRegistrationBean to capture all requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter

I want to use `FilterRegistrationBean` to pass all request throw a filter.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<JwtApplicationFilter> JWTApiFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<JwtApplicationFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<JwtApplicationFilter>();
    registration.setFilter(new JwtApplicationFilter());
    //In case you want the filter to apply to specific URL patterns only
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/xxx");
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/xxx/**");
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/base/");
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/xxx/*");
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/");
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/**");
    return registration;
}
```

I had tried all this patterns and more, I have only one controller with `/base`-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/base/")
public class BaseController {
   /***
}
```

And in my application.properties -

```
 server.servlet.context-path =/xxx
```

JwtApplicationFilter -

```
public class JwtFilterLogin extends GenericFilterBean {

    private FilterHandlers loginHandler;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtFilterLogin.class);
    public static final String HEADER_AUTH = "Authorization";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httprequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpresponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        LOGGER.info("JwtFilterLogin for URI=" + httprequest.getRequestURI()); //not logging or stops at debug

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing `registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");` to match all requests.